# Reactive forms value is an object of type { "value" : "therealname"} instead of just "therealname"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Template Code:

```
<div>name: {{fg.get('name').value | json}}</div>
```

---

When I create the reactive form with

**#1** the following code

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({name: "therealname"});
```

div has,

```
name: therealname
```

**#2** But with either of the following

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({name: [{ value: "therealname"}] });
this.fg = this.fb.group({name: this.fb.control({ value: "therealname"}) });
```

div has this

```
name: {"value": "therealname"}
```

..leaving my scalp soar (because of scratching).

The **#2** doesn't make much sense, `therealname` is at 
 `fg.get('name').value.value` !!?!

**Note:** The reason for preferring **#2** is, that would help have `disabled` option added while creating the `fg`.

Comment: I can't answer your question about the object type, but, if it is any help, you can easily enable / disable controls from your .ts file by doing something like this:  fg.controls.name.disable(), immediately after you have initialized it.

Comment: Ìf you want use an object like {value:'myvalue} it's **mandatory** indicate disabled, so you need write `{value:'myvalue',disabled:true}`, `{value:'myvalue',disabled:false}` or `myvalue`, else Angular undestand that your FormControl store an object -yes a formControl can be store not only a string or number else arrays, objects.., see the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#constructor() when talk about "formstate"

Answer (score 0):

The formBuilder also acceps objects, and that is what you are passing in case 2. It can be quite useful when you have a complex object which you want to display, providing a calculated, custom value besides an id e.g. It is quite flexible on one hand, but on the other hand you should use the right syntax for your use case:

```
this.fg = this.fb.group(this.fb.control({name: "therealname"})
```

or like you proposed:

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({name: "therealname"});
```